# Risk assessment for using draw knife/shave horse with children?

Tags: safety, gear, wooden

I work at a school and we have a green woodwork area. Which is awesome!

I’d like to work towards using a shave horse and draw knives with the children there, aged 8-16 years.

I’ve used shave horses and draw knives a fair bit, but have also heard from different people that they are ‘very foolproof and safe’... but then from others, that you can get horrible injuries and they may be quite dangerous, like on this compendium of Newspaper cuttings of drawknife injuries:

https://blog.lostartpress.com/2016/03/05/the-deadly-knee-hating-drawknife/

I will need a written risk assessment in order to run this activity at schools, but I can’t find any publicly available online- has anyone seen/know of one?

Is a draw knife designed to be safely used with a shave horse, or can a draw knife be safely used without a shave horse?

Comment: Is this an outdoor subject? I would guess not but I would not know where it would fit.

Comment: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/ ?